# mysql select if field row is blank substitute data from another field on sametable

Tags: mysql, select, field, substitution

```
uid     external
rn345   --
ev456   --  
--      Peter
```

So I have the above table and I want to select the uid however I also wanted to substitute the value on the "external" field to the "uid" field if the value is blank.
So essentially, I would get the following:

UID
rn345
ev456
Peter

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `coalesce`, which returns the second value if the first one is `null`:

```
select  coalesce(uid, external)
from    yourTable
```

**Edit**

If the `uid` field is blank instead of `null`, you'll have to use a `case` statement instead

```
select  case when uid is null or uid = '' then external else uid end
from    yourTable
```

Comment: Hmmm. I tried but i dont get the value from external.